# WP CPT Custom Sortable Column in Admin Dashboard Sort Order Random

Tags: custom-post-types, columns

I am trying to add sorting to the custom posts list on the ID column in the admin dashboard, however, I would like to override the behavior of Sorting. Currently, it sorts by ascending or descending order, I want the order to be random. How can we sort by random Order? For example something like the [Shuffle](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_shuffle.asp) function?

```php
add_filter( 'manage_edit-mycpt_sortable_columns', 'set_custom_mycpt_sortable_columns' );

function set_custom_mycpt_sortable_columns( $columns ) {
  $columns['post_id'] = 'post_id';
  return $columns;
}
```